# Looking for Laravel php developer to resolve updating function with image uploading its not working

Tags: php, laravel

It's my update function and it's not showing image when I echo $fileName. It's not working like it was I want to make it with the condition if there is any image then update that image otherwise leave that I tried many times but it's not working.

```
public function update(Request $request, Header $header)
{

    if($request->hasFile('headerimg')){
        $fileName = $request->file('headerimg')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('headerimg')->move('uploads/header',$fileName);
    }

    $header->title = $request->title;
    $header->discription = $request->discription;
    $header->keywords = $request->keywords;
    $header->headerimg = $fileName;
    $header->h2 = $request->h2;
    $header->breadcumb = $request->breadcumb;
    $header->category = $request->category;
    $header->save();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.headers.index')->with('success', 'Packages Edited Successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code edit image and if image was not selected the old image will remain same without any error.

```
public function update(Request $request, Header $header)
{
    $file = $request->headerimg;
    $id = $request->id;
    if($file == ''){
        $arr['header'] = Header::select()->where($id);
        $fileName = $header['headerimg'];
    }
    else{

    $fileName = $request->file('headerimg')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('headerimg')->move('uploads/header',$fileName);

    }
    $header->title = $request->title;
    $header->discription = $request->discription;
    $header->keywords = $request->keywords;
    $header->headerimg = $fileName;
    $header->h2 = $request->h2;
    $header->breadcumb = $request->breadcumb;
    $header->category = $request->category;
    $header->save();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.headers.index')->with('success', 'Page Edited Successfully');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your problem is in your view.
Maybe you forget to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or your input name does not match with mapped controller variable.

For find the exact problem use `dd($request)` and `dd($request->file('headerimg'))` and see can you get request correct or not.